# Can't figure why Ajax return error even when I return json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I've seen the question asked multiple time and a lot of answers about it but none resolve my own problem and I realy don't understand where this could come from.

How come I'm returning a json content with my controller but still access the error part of my Ajax request?

This is my Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../ajax/addArticle',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {
        title : $('#title').val(),
        content :  CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData(),
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data == "Posted"){
            alert('Article posté');
            window.location = "/blog";
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
          console.log(e);
    }
});
```

And my controller return this :

```
$data = ['data' => 'Posted'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = json_encode($data);
return $data;
```

However this is the output :

[image: Screen of netwok]

Comment: Where is the error? The Status Code of the header is 200... What do you see in the response tab?

Comment: shouldn't it be echo?

Comment: `Content-Length: 0`

Comment: try if(obj.data. == "Posted")

Comment: return doesn't "print" the value, you must use `echo`, or `die()` (last one finishes PHP script execution after printing the response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this on the server:

```
echo json_encode($data);
// $data = json_encode($data);
// return $data;
```

The server doesn't echo anything at the moment, so that's why the request fails, since you have a `dataType: 'json'` ajax that doesn't get a JSON response from the server.

Comment: 'Right ! But why shall I echo something and not only return it ?

Comment: Because you should return it if it was inside a function, and even then, you  still had to `echo yourJsonReturningFunction();`

Comment: @Baldráni `return` doesn't send an output, which you need to receive something with ajax. It just just ends a function and returns a value to the function call. Whereas `echo`  actually sends an output.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax returns are responses from the server interpreted as text (or HTML) output
Your code should be :

```
$data = ['data' => 'Posted']; 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
$data = json_encode($data);
echo $data;
```